# How to know the DoT and arcane power usage of the wizard's channels spells

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The [Ray of Frost](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/ray-of-frost) and [Disintegrate](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/disintegrate) spells tell you that they cost 20 AP (without runes) to cast but don't tell how much they cost over time. And they say that they do 215/155% of weapon damage but don't say at over what time period it's done.

- How can I get that information?
- What is the time it takes the Disintegrate rune Intensify to reach 202% of weapon damage?
- Does the Ray of Frost rune Cold Blood reduces the cost over time of casting as well?

**EDIT:** When I say DoT, I mean during the time that the spell is on a monster, and not a DoT affect that stays after the spell was finished casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it deals 215% of your DPS. DPS = Damage per second, so you multiply that value by 2.15 to get the damage per second.

- I do not think that it has DoT, only the time that you hit an enemy counts. To get info of cost over time I would measure how long does it take to get your AP down to 0. Then you use a simple formula: CostOverTime = (YourMaxAP-20)/TimeSpent
- No idea, didn't find any information for it
- No, only the initial cost of 20 AP is removed

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if you have a 200 - 400 weapon with 1.5 AS ==> 450 DPS

your ray will do bettwen (2.15 * 200 * int/100) and (2.15 * 400 * int/100) every 0.66 sec using 20 arcane power each time
So with your 100 arcane power will take about 3.33 sec to be out of power without considering regen ;-)